# how can I increase the percentage by 1% with just one click

Tags: javascript, html

I want the percentage to increase by 1% every second with just one click on the increase button and the same for the decrease button but with the percentage taking -1% off each second. Right now I have my code correct but it is taking multiple clicks on the increase button to get to 100%, I just want one click and it will increase by 1% every second until it hits 100% and decreases by 1% every second if the decrease button is clicked.

```js
function value() {
  var x = document.getElementById("number").getAttribute("aria-precentnow");
  return x;
}

function rvalue(precent) {
  document.getElementById("number").setAttribute("aria-precentnow", precent);
  document.getElementById("number").setAttribute("style", "width: " + precent + "%;");
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = (precent + "%");
}


function increase() {
  var i = value();
  if (i <= 100) {
    i++;
    rvalue(i);
  } else {
    alert("Congrats you hit 100%");
  }
}

function decrease() {
  var x = value();
  rvalue(x - 1);
}

function reset() {
  var y = value();
  rvalue(y = 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div id="number" class="progress-bar" role="number" style="width: 0%;" aria-precentnow="0" aria-precentmin="0" aria-precentmax="100" id="number">0</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
  <button onclick="decrease()">Decrease</button>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  <p id="precent"> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Gunther, sorry, my edit has overwritten yours, didnt intent to

Comment: No worries, I think I've edited again by mistake actually.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive timeout function calling your existing increase/decrease should do the trick:

The `increaseAuto`/`decreaseAuto` functions here will call the normal increase/decrease, but also re-call itself again after 1 second.

You can also use `clearTimeout(autoTimeout)` anywhere (E.g. when you reach 100% or reset) to stop the automatic progression.

```
function increaseAuto() {
  // Clear any existing timeout (As this would carry on when you try to switch direction)
  clearTimeout(autoTimeout)
  // Run the normal increase function
  increase()
  // Set a timeout to trigger this again in 1 second
  autoTimeout = setTimeout(increaseAuto, 1000)
}
```

Full example:

```js
// - New code
// This variable is used to keep track of the timeout
var autoTimeout = null

// This function will trigger the increase, but also call itself again after 1 second
function increaseAuto() {
  clearTimeout(autoTimeout)
  increase()
  autoTimeout = setTimeout(increaseAuto, 1000)
}

// This is the same as the above, but for decrease
function decreaseAuto() {
  clearTimeout(autoTimeout)
  decrease()
  autoTimeout = setTimeout(decreaseAuto, 1000)
}

// - Existing code with minor clearTimeouts added:
function value() {
  var x = document.getElementById("number").getAttribute("aria-precentnow");
  return x;
}

function rvalue(precent) {
  document.getElementById("number").setAttribute("aria-precentnow", precent);
  document.getElementById("number").setAttribute("style", "width: " + precent + "%;");
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = (precent + "%");
}

function increase() {
  var i = value();
  if (i <= 100) {
    i++;
    rvalue(i);
  } else {
    alert("Congrats you hit 100%");
    // Once you hit 100% stop ticking upwards
    clearTimeout(autoTimeout)
  }
}

function decrease() {
  var x = value();
  rvalue(x - 1);
}

function reset() {
  var y = value();
  rvalue(y = 0);
  clearTimeout(autoTimeout)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div id="number" class="progress-bar" role="number" style="width: 0%;" aria-precentnow="0" aria-precentmin="0" aria-precentmax="100" id="number">0%</div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button onclick="increaseAuto()">Increase</button>
  <button onclick="decreaseAuto()">Decrease</button>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

  <p id="precent"> </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `progressBar` attribute along with the `textContent`.

```js
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress > .progress-bar');

const getProgress = () => parseInt(progressBar.getAttribute('aria-precentnow'), 10);

const setProgress = (val) => {
  progressBar.setAttribute('aria-precentnow', val);
  progressBar.textContent = `${val}%`;
  progressBar.style.width = `${val}%`
}

const addProgress = (amount) => {
  const val = getProgress() + amount;
  setProgress(val > 100 ? 100 : val < 0 ? 0 : val);
};

window.increase = () => addProgress(1);
window.decrease = () => addProgress(-1);
window.reset = () => setProgress(0);
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  background: #F88;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div id="number" class="progress-bar" role="number" style="width: 0%;" aria-precentnow="0" aria-precentmin="0" aria-precentmax="100" id="number">0%</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
  <button onclick="decrease()">Decrease</button>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  <p id="precent"> </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the percentage to increase by 1% every second with just one
> click on the increase button and the same for the decrease button but
> with the percentage taking -1% off each second.

Try this:

```js
let direction = 1, current = 0, timer = 0, progressElm = document.getElementById("number")

// updates the dom
function update() {
  progressElm.setAttribute("aria-precentnow", current);
  progressElm.setAttribute("style", "width: " + current + "%");
  progressElm.innerHTML = current + "%";
}

// sets direction
function increase() {
  direction = 1
  current += direction // if you want increase on click too
  if (!timer) run()
}

// ...
function decrease() {
  direction = -1
  current += direction // if you want decrease on click too
  if (!timer) run()
}

// resets the state
function reset() {
  clearInterval(timer)
  direction = 1
  current = 0
  timer = 0
  update()
}

// runs the timer/logic
function run() {
  clearInterval(timer)
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    current += direction
    update()

    if (current >= 100) decrease()
    if (current <= 0) increase()
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div id="number" class="progress-bar" role="number" style="width: 0%;" aria-precentnow="0" aria-precentmin="0" aria-precentmax="100" id="number">0%</div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
  <button onclick="decrease()">Decrease</button>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

  <p id="precent"> </p>

</div>
```